# R delete specific row in condition

Tags: r, row

This could be easy question, sorry about that. I want to delete the specific row in column conditions. If the 3rd row's C column (only the 3rd row) is not equal to 1, I want to drop the 3rd row, otherwise (like in the example) I want to keep the data. Please see the example below.

`data<- data.frame(A=c(2.9,1.3,2.5), B=c(8,9,10), C=c(0,0,1))`

`ifelse(data_3rd_row != 1, drop_3rd_row, keep_all_rows)`

Answer (score 2):

`ifelse` is vectorized, and the shape of the output will always be the same shapes as the input. For something like this you want the non-vectorized `if(){}`

```
data <- data.frame(A=c(2.9,1.3,2.5), B=c(8,9,10), C=c(0,0,1))

if(data$C[3] != 1) {
  data <- data[-3, ]
}
```